# Add border color to range knob ionic-range

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using the ion-range to add a range slider and would like to add a border to the range-knob. Since its ionic4 and the range-knob is a part of the shadow dom i cannot directly change the border using the border property for the range knob. I have attached the image which I am trying to achieve.A white border around the range knob. The existing properties only has a box shadow property that is close to my requirement but still doesnt give results exactly like the image. How can I add a border to the knob?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

page.scss

```
ion-range{
    --knob-background: #02a7de;
    --bar-background-active: #02a7de;
    --bar-background: #02a7de;
    --bar-height: 6px;
    --knob-size: 18px;
    --knob-border-radius: 50%;
    --bar-border-radius: 20px;
    --knob-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #fff;
}
```

Comment: For me just me just --knob-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #fff;