# How to fix --bar-background-active: not working?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ion-range-slider

I am trying to customize the `ion-range` in my app based on the wireframe. I tried to use  `--bar-background-active` but seems not working. Please refer to my codes below. I removed the `color="primary"` in the `ion-range attribute` since the bar-background is blue also, I need to change it to gray to align with the wireframe. Hope you can help me. Thank you

**Wireframe**
[image]

**Actual** [image]

*.html*

```
<ion-range
    class="range-position"
    min="1"
    max="6"
    dualknobs="true"
    pin="false"
    snaps="true"
    ticks="false"
    //removed the color="primary"
    list="tickmarks"
    [(ngModel)]="range"
    (ionChange)="changeFunction($event)"
  >
  </ion-range>
```

**.scss**

```
  ion-range {
  --bar-background-active: #0e82c1;
  --bar-background: gray;
  --bar-height: 0.5px;
  --knob-size: 18px;
  display: block;
 }
```

**ionic info**

```
  Ionic:

  Ionic CLI                     : 6.13.0
  Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.4.3
  @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
  @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
  @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
  @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

  Cordova:

  Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
  Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.1
  Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 21 other plugins)        

  Utility:

  cordova-res : not installed
  native-run  : not installed

  System:

  NodeJS : v15.3.0 
  npm    : 7.5.4
  OS     : Windows 10
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58656662/5909026

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Thank you for trying to help me, but I also tried that solution but still not working.

Comment: It seems to be working fine in [this Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66433214?file=src/app/pages/home/home.page.scss). Could you please try to reproduce the issue there?

Comment: Also what version of ionic are you using? add out of  `ionic info` to your question

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I added the ionic info above

Comment: @Titus were you able to reproduce the issue in the Stackblitz demo that I shared in the comment above?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I resolve the problem that you need to remove the `color` attribute. And it works perfectly :D. Good luck

[image]

Comment: Remove the attribute: `color` and it works.