# Put yellow dot inside the ion-range slider knob

Tags: ionic4, ion-range-slider

[image]

can anyone help me with how can I make this yellow dot within the ion-range knob?

Comment: The only available options seem to be, as mentioned in this answer: [Add border color to range knob ionic-range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640381/add-border-color-to-range-knob-ionic-range). Also the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/range) do not mention the option (AFAIK)

Comment: this is not the solution that u provide. I need yellow dot inside the knob.